# Passing php variable to javascript in a different file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having problems with passing php variables to javascript. 
It does pass through the variable that is declared at the top, but I don't know how to call the function to get the new version of variable after the IF statement is done.

```
$info = "A message";

if (true){

    $info = 'Message to be passed';


}
```

The script that is used to pass the php variable to javascript file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var info = "<?php echo $info; ?>";
</script>
```

I was wondering what could I do to fix this problem?

Comment: php is run server-side (first), and javascript is run client-side (second, after page is loaded). Javascript cannot change a php variable, unless a call is sent back to the server, ie. ajax. You can just change the value in javascript

Comment: please add the real if statement, that could be the why the if statement isn't running. please clarify your question, did you want a function to get new value at any time or just the updated value from the start

Comment: I do not get it, if your `php if` is before your `<script>` , then you would get what you want! So what is your real problem? please explain more and please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking more questions

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I wanted to know if there was a way to get the function to get a new value at any time. This is because the if statement is being used to change the value after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way (this requires both files to be PHP files):

```
<?php

require_once "your_php_file_here.php"; // Change to your PHP file here

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var info = "<?php echo $info; ?>";
alert(info);

</script>
```

*This will only allow you to get the value on page load. You need to reload the page if you want it to get a new value.*

The (in my opinion) better way (the file can be HTML) using Ajax:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var info;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'your_php_file_here.php'); // Change to your PHP file here
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        info = xhr.responseText;
        alert(info);
    } else {
        alert('Request failed: ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();

</script>
```

*This can be put in a function and called as many times as you want. It can get the new value without the need to reload the page.*

For this to work, you need to change your PHP code to:

```
$info = "A message";

if (true){

    $info = 'Message to be passed';

}

echo $info;
```

I did not add support for IE6 and below because I think it's about time we stop supporting browsers that lost support by their developers many years ago.